# Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::getImageUrl() deprecated since 1.1.5

Tags: magento-1.9, product, magento-1, best-practice

I found some interesting methods in the product model

```
/**
 * Return re-sized image URL
 *
 * @deprecated since 1.1.5
 * @return string
 */
public function getImageUrl()
{
    return (string)$this->_getImageHelper()->init($this, 'image')->resize(265);
}

/**
 * Return re-sized small image URL
 *
 * @deprecated since 1.1.5
 * @param int $width
 * @param int $height
 * @return string
 */
public function getSmallImageUrl($width = 88, $height = 77)
{
    return (string)$this->_getImageHelper()->init($this, 'small_image')->resize($width, $height);
}
```

There's also `getThumbnailUrl()` which work in the same way as `getSmallImageUrl()`

Unfortunately, the `@deprecated` doc comment does not say anything about a replacement, so I wonder what should be used instead.

The method is not used in the core and in Magento 1.9 the templates always instantiate the image helper directly.

**However, I wonder why I should not use this shortcut and why it has been deprecated in the first place.** I'm sure it won't be removed now, if it hasn't been since 1.1.5. `getImageUrl()` might not be very useful because it resizes to a fixed value, but `getSmallImageUrl()` and `getThumbnailUrl()` take `$width` and `$height` parameters.

Comment: Not sure if creating the `magento-1.1.5` tag was worth it ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's what I call stillborn code.

Basically the deprecated flag is not accurate as [those methods were not here in 1.1.4](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/5b1e92d8945ec184a47cb86d1e6c24d8c7aefa11/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L1405) and [the deprecated flag has been added with the methods in 1.1.5](https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/1.1.5/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Product.php#L1249)

My assumption is that it was code from someone who wanted to improve things and never got used.

**The only reason I would not use this code** is that it returns a string. Thus you cannot make more modifications to the image (aspect ratio, quality, frame, transparency etc...)